# mpdboot and mpdtrace gives Alarm Clock as a result

Tags: virtualization, parallels, mpd, mpi

I try to execute

```
mpdboot -n 2 -f /home/user/mpd.hosts
```

and then

```
mpdtrace
```

However, both of them return:

```
Alarm clock
```

I have a virtual machine with mpd installed on it.
I copied the `.vdi` (the hard drive) to another machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found it. This indicated a **licence problem**.

The reason is that I installed Licensed `mpd` (not free `mpd`) in my virtual machine.

Then I copied the virtual machine to another computer.

That´s why the `mpd` can not be used in the new machine. I should update the licence.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably try updating your version of MPICH. MPD hasn't be used for years at this point and the newer versions don't require it.